# How to get value of many selected radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using JavaScript to get value from the radio boxes to insert it to the database as a string. What I need is that I have more than 2 radio boxes. How would I make use of Javascript to add the values to my database?

Here is my code:

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="company_grp" class="largerCheckbox" value='Sentinel' checked="checked">
    Sentinel GM
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="company_grp" class="largerCheckbox" value='GuardTrack'>
    GuardTrack
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="company_grp" class="largerCheckbox" value='GuardingProduct'>
    Guarding Product
</td>
```

```js
if (!document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[0].checked && !document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[1].checked && !document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[2].checked) { 
    alert("Please Select the company group does this client belong's to!"); 
    form.company_grp.focus();
    return false;
}
```

It's very tricky but I don't get the correct value. When I select the 3rd radio, it doesn't add to the database but instead it reloads the page.

Comment: You've got two questions here. To get the value of the checkboxes in your HTML, use `$('input[name=company_grp]:checked').val();`. To put the value in your database you'd need to submit your form (or use AJAX) and then have your server-side code update the data store.

Comment: Thank for you help. But I'm not using a checkbox but a Radiobox instead. I would like to keep the same format but when I use 2 radioBox, the javascript works well. But if I wanna use 3 or many radiobox, the JavaScript does not work. That is what I'm asking. ex: `if (!document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[0].checked && !document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[1].checked` Works but `if (!document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[0].checked && !document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[1].checked && !document.frmAdd_Visit.company_grp[2].checked)
{ ` Doesn't work. why? what do i need to do?

Comment: `But I'm not using a checkbox but a Radiobox instead` I know - this mankes no difference to what I suggested. From your second comment it sounds like you just want to detect when *no* radio has been chosen, is that correct?

Comment: No, I would like to know, if I have many RadioBox with the same JavaScript, How would I format it and make it work?

Comment: @MichealP. i think you have problems with basically understanding radioboxes. when you use a radio-group (like you are in your example: all of your radios belong to the same group because they got the same `name` value) you only can check one out of it. so why even bother checking for every single one? if you want to be able to check multiple options, you should use checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to get value form radio box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="company_grp"]:checked').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery code below returns the value:

```
$('input[name=company_grp]:checked').val()
```

Comment: Thanks for try guys, but still return no action! the page reload without adding the 3rd RadioBox. please check my HTML code.

Comment: yeah because you `return false`... @MichealP.

Answer (score 0):

can use radio type checked as $(':radio:checked')

```
var selectedvalue;
if($(':radio:checked').length > 0){
    $(':radio:checked').each(function (i) {
           selectedvalue = $(this).val();
        });
}
console.log(selectedvalue);
```

Comment: Hi David, Is it possible for you to stick just to the same format that I use for my JS and Edit from there? Thanks

Comment: yes , you can stick that where adding database action take place.so it will dynamically change your selected radio value.@MichealP

Answer (score -2):

Here what I found and it working well for me.

```
function test_company_grp() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("company_grp");
    var found = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            alert(radios[i].value);
            found = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == 1)
    {
    alert("Please Select the company group does this client belong's to!");
    }    
}
```